# Unity HDRP transparent material back-face rendering/front face culling

Tags: unity, shaders, materials, culling, hdrp

I try to render an object with 2 different transparent materials. One should only render the back faces (higher opacity/more color) and one only the front faces (lower opacity/less color). The purpose is to show another object inside the mesh better, while keeping the more saturated color on the back faces.

I tried to only render the back faces using a  shader graph, but it seems to be impossible to only render back faces with TRANSPARENT material. With opaque materials, it was not a problem to isolate the back faces.

Is there a way to only render back faces of a transparent material, and overlap them with another material that only renders front faces?

(btw. this is the model, I need it for. The bones should pretty much preserve their details/color, while the jello is a rich green (screenshot from blender))

[image: the problem child]

Any help is very appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Back faces won't have any lighting data available to them. If you need that, you're probably better off having another copy of the mesh with inverted normals. You may be able to achieve this particular effect with only the front layer though, if you attenuate the transparency with a depth texture (which should capture your skeleton).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I wish I could achieve the effect with only the front layer! unfortunately in my rig the bones move/rotate seperately to the rest of the mesh, so baking them in anthickness map would be a no brainer, right? How bad would the 2 mesh solution bebfor performance? is it comparable to 2 materials on one mesh?